# Jenkins Localhost URL requires Jenkins war file to be run each time on WIN 7 machine

Tags: jenkins, localhost

I have established a local Jenkins connection successfully in a WIN 7 machine and I have scheduled a job to run periodically(everyday morning 9AM). But it fails to connect to the localhost URL because in-order to connect to local host, it seems that I have to run the Jenkins.war file each time. i.e., the command prompt should be kept open with the message Jenkins is up and running. If it is closed, local host is not getting connected.
But the same setup is working successfully in Win XP machine. Even though the machine gets logged off, Jenkins automatically runs the job at the scheduled time on the server. Here I just ran the Jenkins war file once during the initial setup. 
Kindly suggest what needs to be done on the WIN 7 machine so that it connects to local host without running war file each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you run the WAR file in jenkins. you will have an option to install it as a service in **`Manage Jenkins`**. This will make the service startup in windows

I doubt the case with XP because if you are running a war file via `cmd` line, then there is no chance of the process surviving once the user gets logged off

Please refer this for your info https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bc166915-436b-4f34-b84b-a8a4adf60cbc/do-windows-services-cease-to-run-once-youve-logged-off-the-username?forum=winservergen